# How to sort items from a newsfeed as last_active_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-design, social-networking, feed

In this question I've got two tables for the database:

- Post (has_many :comments)
- ActivityFeed (belongs_to item, :polymorphic)
- Comment (belongs_to :post)

Suppose that inside a group in facebook happen these sequential actions:

1. User A posted a status "Status 1"
2. User B posted a status "Status 2"

and then each one of these 2 **posts** has triggered the creation of a FeedItem (Activity) for the group.

Now when the user loads the page, the feed activities are sorted by created_at/updated_at.
The feed activities are a polymorphic set of objects (can be post, photo, poll, file...).

If in a second moment User A comments the post of user B, the correct order for the feed should now be:

1. "Status 2"
2. "Status 1"

So what should happen when User A comments on a "Status 2"? Should I have to find the related Post (where the comment is being added) and update the timestamp from the activity that the Post is related to?

I need some advices for this. Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :post, touch: true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :comments
  act_as_activity -> on_create will create a Activity representing this object
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :item, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :parent, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So the feed query will lookup for the activities table, since I can have multiple types of objects in the feed. And the timestamp must be refresh in this table when comment a post, because the query is done in Activity table:

```
SELECT * FROM Activity 
              ORDER BY updated_at
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bdares' idea of using an after_create callback it might look something like this.

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :post, touch: true
  after_create do 
     self.post.activity.last_update_at = Time.now
     self.post.activity.save!
  end
end
```

This means that you're sorting `Activity` by that `last_update_at` field.

Comment: I was thinking in something much similar to that. The only thing i'm concerned is performance os writes. But I should think in improves later. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, Post should be displayed in "most recent" order. The addition of a Comment on a Post should refresh that "most recent" time.

Here's something to try. There's a options for an belongs_to association called :touch. By adding this option, the addition of a Comment on a Post should cause the updated_at field on the Post to be updated whenever a Comment is added (or deleted) from the association.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

For example:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :post, touch: true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

then you do your sort on the Post instance's :updated_at field.

Comment: The existence of the `:touch` option is awesome.  My first thought was an `after_create` hook on `Comment` but the functionality is built in!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Touch is nice! Your answer is not wrong, but the query isn't at the table Posts, since I can have multiple object type. See my edit. Thanks!

Comment: Based on your update, how do you reference an Activity from a Post. Is there a ````has_one :activity```` or ````has_many :activity```` on the ````Post````?

Comment: @GSP with has_one :activity

Comment: @GSP What I am seeing is that: comment on post will touch the post, which should touch the activity. But I don't know, it seems wrong.. But I don't have any other ideas

Comment: I would consider using bdares' idea of using the ````after_create```` callback. I'll post an answer and see if that helps.